# Python BeautifulSoup find_all returns empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```py
from urllib
import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://recreation.northeastern.edu/"

result = requests.get(url)

doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

marino = doc.find_all(text="Marino")

print(marino)
```

This is my code. When I do it on other websites, it returns a list with strings, but on this website it returns an empty list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, if you use `find_all(text=...)` in combination with `re.compile()`

Perhaps you want to try this:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://recreation.northeastern.edu/"
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
marino = doc.find_all(text=re.compile("Marino "))
print(marino)
```